# Compilation error for RISCV gcc when try to include -lcrypto

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc, ld

I am running openssl benchmarks on Ubuntu Linux. Initially, there was some problem with the missing library. Later I fixed it by installing the library with the installation command **sudo apt-get install libssl-dev**. When I compiled using gcc command **gcc sha256t.c -o sha -lcrypto**, it generates binary but when compiled using RISCV gcc command **riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc sha256.S -o sha.riscv -lcrypto**, it throws the following link error.

/home/user_name/fpga-zynq/rocket-chip/riscv-tools/riscv/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-elf/6.1.0/../../../../riscv64-unknown-elf/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status.

How to link the -lcrypto in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You need a libcrypto compiled for the riscv64 architecture.

What you installed with `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev` is a libcrypto compiled for your host architecture (likely x86_64), it cannot be used for cross-compiling.

If you can't find a pre-built libcrypto for riscv64, you might have to compile it yourself, with that same riscv64 cross-compiler you're using.

Automating this is what [yocto](https://www.yoctoproject.org/) or [buildroot](https://buildroot.org/) is all about.

Comment: Thanks @David Faure